# call js inside php not worked

Tags: javascript, php

I have issue with script js inside php so i want ipnut get the somme of the value return by function js in dispaly in input with condition in php inside the input in below my script php:

```
function getSum(){               
    let NotePresence= document.getElementById("NotePresence").value;
    let NoteValidation= document.getElementById("NoteValidation").value;
    let NoteEvaluation= document.getElementById("NoteEvaluation").value;
    let t=NotePresence+NoteValidation+NoteEvaluation;
    return t;
}
```

calling in php:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex">
    <input readonly="" style='width: auto' type="text" 
            name="NoteFinale" id="NoteFinale" 
            class="form-control" maxlength="2" 
            value="<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">getSum();</script>';?>
            size="4" />
    <label for="">&nbsp;/80</label>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If you insert HTML tags inside a `value` attribute it'll be handled as plain text. You won't get scripts executed or HTML rendered. Whether you use PHP to print this markup doesn't make any change.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `script` element inside an attribute value.

If you want to assign a value to the attribute from JS, then:

- Put the `script` somewhere after the element in the DOM
- Find the element with DOM methods (e.g. `document.getElementById`)
- Assign the value to the element with DOM

Note, however, that since you *should* know the initial values for the three elements you are reading from, you should be able to eliminate JS entirely and just do this with PHP.

---

```
$NotePresence = 50;
$NoteValidation = 100;
$NoteEvaluation = 150;

<input name="NotePresence" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($NotePresence)">
<input name="NoteValidation" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($NoteValidation)">
<input name="NotePresence" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($NotePresence)">
<input name="NoteFinale" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($NotePresence + $NoteValidation = $NoteEvaluation)">
```

---

That is, assuming you want to combine them when the document loads.

If you want to do it later, then…

In **JavaScript** you would need to move the code into a function that you call when a suitable event (e.g. `change` on an input or `submit` on a form occurs).

In **PHP** you would need to move the code to the place the data is submitted **to** and combine the data from `$_POST`.

Comment: on change the input?